# How to test void method that changes class variable in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm not used to testing or writing Angular code so I'm wondering how do you test a method (in this case `changeMyMonth`) that returns void and changes a class variable?

```
date: Date = new Date();
private dateArray: Date[];

private getMaxDaysInMonth(): number {
  return new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
}

changeMyMonth(amount: number): void {
  this.date= new Date(
    this.date.getFullYear(),
    this.date.getMonth() + amount, 1);
  this.dateArray= this.getArrayOfDates(this.getMaxDays(), this.date);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentName);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should test changeMyMonth', () => {
    component.changeMyMonth(3);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.date).toEqual(/* something */);
    expect(component['dateArray']).toEqual(/* something */);
});

it('should test changeMyMonth', () => {
    let returnValue = component['getMaxDaysInMonth']();

    expect(returnValue).toEqual(/* something */);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very beautiful, but you can access a private field just fine by "bypassing" Typescript checks using a cast to any;

```
let valueToCheck = (<any>yourComponent).dateArray;
```

The `private` modifier has no impact on the transpiled javascript code.